# Equations help please here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve

$$(y'+1)=\frac{(x+y)^m}{(x+y)^n + (x+y)^p}$$

The problem is that I haven't seen any differential equation like this.Should  I subtitute something first?

Answer (score 4):

Let's set $z:=z(x)=x+y\;$ then your equation becomes :
$$z'=\frac {z^m}{z^n+z^p}$$
$$z^{n-m}z'+z^{p-m}z'=1$$
As indicated by Mark Bennet we must take care to powers equal to $-1\ $ here...

If $\,m\not = n+1$ and $m\not = p+1$ then :
$$\frac{z^{n-m+1}}{n-m+1}+\frac{z^{p-m+1}}{p-m+1}=C+x$$

That is, I think, the implicit equation :

$$\frac{(x+y)^{n-m+1}}{n-m+1}+\frac{(x+y)^{p-m+1}}{p-m+1}=C+x$$

For $\,m = n+1$ or $m = p+1\ $ replace the corresponding term(s) by $\ \log |x+y|$.

Comment: There are some special cases to consider e.g. $n-m+1=0$

Comment: Thanks @Mark I'll update my answer.